# Why i Get Space top of the tableView after push some ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

> **This Screen is "C" ViewController and it has second.Storyboard**

**This Screen is getting space top of the table after push "A" Viewcontroller it has Main.Storyboard**

[image]

**Same Viewcontroller and same code but push from "B" ViewController it has Main.Storyboard.**

[image]

Comment: What space? What is "C"?

Comment: "C" is given image ViewController and space is you are seen purple color above cell

Comment: Can you shouw us your autolayout setup in Interface builder?

Answer (score 2):

Try unchecking `Adjust scroll View Insert` Property of View Controller
[image]

Comment: I do also this.

Answer (score 1):

Drag the top constraint of the tableView as an IBOutlet and do this

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews
 {

    self.tableviewTopCon.constant = 0

    self.layoutSubviews()

 }
```

Comment: "self.tableviewTopCon.constant = 0"  What is tableviewTopCon?

Comment: it's the top constraint of the tableview dragged as an IBOutlet from storyboard to control it's constant value at runtime

Comment: Oh, I see.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try chainging content inset.

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-36, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: if I try your code but when I push from "B" Viewcontroller then it will take -36 means it will cut cell.

Comment: This is totally wrong. You think Apple would want you to set something to some negative value out of box? Even if this would work it would be hack. This is probably caused by wrong autolayout.

Comment: may be. what i figure out is tableview inherits content inset from scroll view. and i fixed mine view using this. if it is hack then correct me i will also apply and keep it in mind.